# how to make ethernet and ieee802.3 frames in scapy python3

Tags: python-3.x, networking, wireshark, scapy, ethernet

```
import scapy.all as scapy

#Here i define some arguments i want to modify at layer 2
payload = "hello, here is my first message!"
destinationMAC = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
sourceMAC = "78:dd:08:cf:fb:8a"
etherTypeHex = "0x0800"
etherType = int(etherTypeHex, 16)

#Here creating a ethernet2 frame 
myEtherFrame = scapy.Ether(
    src=sourceMAC,
    dst=destinationMAC,
    type=etherType) #there is no further details like FCS, or payload!
```

I want to make a perfect ethernet frame and send it, also i want to make ieee802.3 either.

another problem is, even though i make ehter frame, in wireshark it appears to be ieee802.3
what is the problem!??

Comment: But Ethernet and 802.3 are the same thing.

Comment: You cannot specify the FCS of your Ethernet frame because this data is managed only by your network interface.  In other words, this is only a mechanism used by your interface and you have no means to control it or see it in scapy.  For the same reason that wireshark never displays the FCS.

Comment: To put a payload in your Ethernet frame you can set its payload attribute: `frame = Ether() ; frame.payload = payload` ; or use the encapsulation operator: `frame = Ether() / payload`.

Comment: thanks you a lot, about the first comment, if i want use 802.3 i should specify "lenght" rather than "ethertype"! also they have different usage like 802.3 used for management protocols like spanning tree and ether2 used for ip-based protocols.